# Getting Error while forecasting on test dataset

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

A novice in forecasting here.
I have data with dates ranging from 01-2018 till 08-2019. The dataset is in weekly intervals. I split up the dataset into train and test dataset and then tried checking the accuracy of the model using `accuracy` function but I am getting the following error here:

Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Dataset:
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1kse.png)

```r
    library(forecast)
    tsCM=ts(df$value, start=c(2018,1,5),end=c(2019,8,2),frequency = 52 )
    traints=window(tsCM, start=c(2018,1), end=c(2018,12))
    testts=window(tsCM,start=c(2019,1),end=c(2019,8))

    mmean=meanf(traints, h=30)
    nnaive=naive(traints, h=30)
    seanaive=snaive(traints, h=30)

    accuracy(mmean, testts)
```

Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
In addition: Warning message:
In window.default(x, ...) : 'start' value not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start` and `end` arguments in `ts()` can take numeric vectors of length 1 or 2, not 3. The third argument is ignored here, so your `tsCM` starts at `c(2018,1)` or week 1 of 2018. The `end` argument is similarly interpreted as `c(2019,8)`, so your time series is only 60 observations in length. The remaining observations are ignored.

The `traints` object contains 12 observations, and you forecast 30 steps ahead, that is to week 42 of 2018. So when you compare against the `testts`, there are no overlapping observations.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my concepts here Rob!. I had a followup question. So my time series is in weekly intervals. is `c()` dependent on frequency?. So if my frequency would have been 12 then `c(2018,1)` would have meant month 1 of 2018?. What happens if my frequency is in decimals?. Shouldn't weekly freq be `365/7`

Comment: Yes, 365/7 would be more accurate than 52. You might consider using our new set of packages which are much better for handling weekly and higher frequency data. See tidyverts.org